# How to place 2 widgets side by side? Final Code appreciated as I am not a coder

Tags: html, css, position

Please see the picture. I added widget code in html file but it always goes below one another! I want to add more widgets too so please guide me accordingly.

Thanks in advance!

Code -

```html
<!-- Nifty50 TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js" async>
    {
      "interval": "5m",
      "width": 425,
      "isTransparent": false,
      "height": 450,
      "symbol": "NSE:NIFTY",
      "showIntervalTabs": true,
      "locale": "in",
      "colorTheme": "light"
    }
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->



<!-- BankNifty TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js" async>
    {
      "interval": "5m",
      "width": 425,
      "isTransparent": false,
      "height": 450,
      "symbol": "NSE:BANKNIFTY",
      "showIntervalTabs": true,
      "locale": "in",
      "colorTheme": "light"
    }
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a wrapper div around your widgets and gave that wrapper `display: flex;` see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more information about flexbox

```html
<style>
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
  }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">

  <!-- Nifty50 TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js" async>
      {
        "interval": "5m",
        "width": 425,
        "isTransparent": false,
        "height": 450,
        "symbol": "NSE:NIFTY",
        "showIntervalTabs": true,
        "locale": "in",
        "colorTheme": "light"
      }
    </script>
  </div>
  <!-- TradingView Widget END -->



  <!-- BankNifty TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js" async>
      {
        "interval": "5m",
        "width": 425,
        "isTransparent": false,
        "height": 450,
        "symbol": "NSE:BANKNIFTY",
        "showIntervalTabs": true,
        "locale": "in",
        "colorTheme": "light"
      }
    </script>
  </div>
  <!-- TradingView Widget END -->
</div>
```

Comment: I saved as .html, still the same thing.. Although shows correctly if I run the snippet here.. Do I have to save the 1st snippet also?

Comment: did you include the css? if you mean the css with "the first snippet" then yes

Comment: I have edited the snippet so you can just copy it and run it as one file

Comment: <style> .widgets-wrapper{ display: flex; } .widgets-wrapper{ display: flex; justify-content: center; } justify-content: space-between justify-content: space-around </style> Thank you. This is not working, what's wrong?

Comment: In my code it's not  .widgets-wrapper but just .wrapper

Comment: I strongly suggest to not use `<style>` tag. I just added an example to link styles properly via `<link>`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)

Try wrapping both widgets into a **Flexbox container** like this

styles.css

```
.widgets-wrapper{
  display: flex;
}
```

somepage.html

```
<div class="widgets-wrapper">

    <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
      <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
      ...
    </div>

    <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
        <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
        ...
    </div>

</div>
```

I'm assuming they both will take 50% and fulfill all the space, but in case you need to align them, use this for centering:

```
.widgets-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Or if you want to have some space between them:

```
justify-content: space-between
```

or, if you want to also keep some space *around* them to not reach left and right end:

```
justify-content: space-around
```

There's a lot of properties and possiblities so I suggest to study it a bit deeper to seize all it's power.

Here are some more useful links:

- [Flexbox basic concepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)
- [CSS Flexbox (W3Schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

---

Try this to make it works properly with the example I provided.

Create a **css** file and name it as **styles.css**

```
.widgets-wrapper{
  display: flex;
}
```

on the same folder your HTML file is. Then, to link it to your HTML, use the `link` tag on your HTML `head`, so the final example should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Your title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="widgets-wrapper">

        <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
            <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
            ...
        </div>
    
        <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
            <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
            ...
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

With `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` you're telling your HTML to link the CSS so the rules you're defining on **styles.css** will apply on your HTML.

This keeps your code more clean and it's way strongly suggested to make it this way instead of applying styles by `<style>` tag on your HTML.

---

**styles.css** variants.

```css
/****************/
/*  Base styles */
/*  Ignore this */
/****************/

body{
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
code{
  padding: 4px;
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
}

.widgets-wrapper{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.widget{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.widget.blue{
  background: lightblue;
}
.widget.coral{
  background: lightcoral;
}
.widget.fifty{
  width: 50%;
}

/*****************/
/* Flex variants */
/*****************/

/* Just apply flexbox to align horizontally */
.widgets-wrapper.flex{
    display: flex;
}

/* Center align */
.widgets-wrapper.centered{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* space-between to separate them */
.widgets-wrapper.space-between{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* space-around to have blank space at both sides of the boxes */
.widgets-wrapper.space-around{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

/* In case your widgets are 50% with each */
.widgets-wrapper.fifty-fifty{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<p>Apply <code>display:flex</code> to align them horizontally</p>
<div class="widgets-wrapper flex">

    <div class="widget blue">
    </div>

    <div class="widget coral">
    </div>

</div>

<p>Apply <code>display: flex; justify-content: center;</code> to center them</p>
<div class="widgets-wrapper centered">

    <div class="widget blue">
    </div>

    <div class="widget coral">
    </div>

</div>

<p>Apply <code>display: flex; justify-content: space-between;</code> to add space between the boxes</p>
<div class="widgets-wrapper space-between">

    <div class="widget blue">
    </div>

    <div class="widget coral">
    </div>

</div>

<p>Apply <code>display: flex; justify-content: space-around;</code> to add space at both sides of the boxes</p>
<div class="widgets-wrapper space-around">

    <div class="widget blue">
    </div>

    <div class="widget coral">
    </div>

</div>

<p>In case your widgets are 50% width each, just applying <code>display: flex;</code> makes the trick</p>
<div class="widgets-wrapper fifty-fifty">

    <div class="widget blue fifty">
    </div>

    <div class="widget coral fifty">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: <style>
.widgets-wrapper{
  display: flex;
}
.widgets-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
justify-content: space-between
justify-content: space-around
</style>

Thank you. This is not working, what's wrong?

Comment: You can go with only the ` .widgets-wrapper{ display: flex; }` and it should work. The other lines are optioinal, and don' t repeat them, they are just different options.

Comment: I suggest you to link styles by `<link>` tag as shown on this example, and here's a snippet with the variations I mentioned early. Hope this is clear and helps you.